# Jquery toggles menu for mobile, potentially leaves it off when resized up to desktop

Tags: jquery, css, nav

I'm currently working on a responsive site with a horizontal navigation menu and switches to a clickable menu icon that expands for mobile. The menu looks fine at desktop resolution and works great on mobile.

My problem happens if I scale my browser down past my resolution breakpoint. It switches to the mobile menu icon and hides my standard menu. If i click the icon the menu shows up. click it again it goes away. everything is fine. When I scale the browser back up the original menu will show up if i left the mobile toggled visible and if i didn't activate the toggle in the first place but if i activate it, then close the mobile menu, then scale back up, the standard menu keeps the toggle hidden aspect and never reappears.

As far as I can tell, I would need the jquery to force the toggle back to visible when i scale back up past my media query breakpoint. but I have no idea how to do that and I haven't found this problem elsewhere online.

```
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
        $("#nav").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
```

is the function I was using:

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">
        <div id="menu-icon"><img src="../img/menu.png"></div>
        <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="default.htm">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="obstacles.htm">Obstacles</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.htm">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.htm">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="sponsor.htm">Sponsor</a></li>
        <li><a href="volunteer.htm">Volunteer</a></li>
        <li><a href="faqs.htm">FAQs/Documents</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

is my navigation menu and:

```
#nav {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:900;
    margin:1em auto;
    display:block;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    margin:1em 2em;
}
#menu-icon {
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
#menu-icon {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    margin:0em auto 1em auto;
}
#nav {
    clear:both;
    z-index:10000;
    padding:5px;
    background:#000;
    border:solid 1px #f1f1eb;
    display:none;
}
}
```

edit: i forgot to add. I tried to work around this by using a separate nav with a different ID that would go hidden when it scaled down, but that had the opposite problem, where half the time I'd scale back up and have 2 nav menus because the jquery #nav would be toggled on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window.resize function to check for viewport and add `$("#nav").show();`

## JS

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //Add a set timeout to prevent resource hogging
    myWinWidth();
});

function myWinWidth() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(winWidth);    
        if(winWidth > 600){
                 $("#nav").show();          
        }
    return false;
};

$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
        $("#nav").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
```

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5DQs8/8/

Comment: Thank you. That works like a charm. I'm just trying to get a hang of the syntax for JS still. So it's just saying that it's forcing #nav to "show" visible any time it's over my resolution breakpoint and anything lower than it lets my original script run through like it was is how I'm reading it.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: @RickRC not a problem.  What helps me is using tools such as Chrome's Developer Tool and monitor the change state of the element.  What was happening in your case is that when the mobile menu was closed, #nav was in a hidden state.  You just need a trigger to remove said state dependent on certain conditions.  Best of luck!